# Select top X records for each group or default

Tags: mysql, optimization, greatest-n-per-group

I have the following schema:

```
users:

id email
1  'user.one@test.com'
2  'user.two@test.com'

video_group:

id title
1  'Group 1'
2  'Group 2'

videos:

id group_id rank title
1  1        1    'Group 1 - Video 1'
2  1        2    'Group 1 - Video 2'
3  2        1    'Group 2 - Video 1'

user_video_play_times:

video_id user_id time last_update
2        1       12   01-02-2018
1        1       120  01-01-2018
```

I need to get the `time`, `user_id`, `video_id`, and `group_id` of the last video played by a user in specific groups, but if there's no records on `user_video_play_times` for a group, the video with the lowest rank should be returned. For example:

```
user_id group_id video_id time
1       1        2        12    -- user.one + group 1
1       2        3        0     -- user one + group 2
```

This is the query I have so far:

```
SELECT
   pt.user_id user_id,
   v.id       video_id,
   g.id       group_id,
   pt.time    time
FROM
   videos v
   INNER JOIN video_groups g ON g.id = v.group_id
   LEFT JOIN user_video_play_times pt ON 
      pt.video_id = v.id AND 
      pt.user_id = 1
   LEFT JOIN (
      SELECT 
         g.id AS g_id,
         MAX(pt.last_update) AS pt_last_update
      FROM
         user_video_play_times pt
         INNER JOIN videos v ON v.id = pt.video_id
         INNER JOIN video_groups g ON g.id = v.group_id
      WHERE
         pt.user_id = 1 AND
         g.id IN (1, 2)
      GROUP BY
         g.id
   ) lpt ON lpt.g_id = g.id AND lpt.pt_last_update = pt.last_update
WHERE
   g.id IN (1, 2)
GROUP BY
   g.id
```

It is sort of working, but...

1. Adding `v.title` to the column selection messes the results for some reason, making everything return only videos with rank 1. Any idea why?
2. Could this query be optimized, or is there another slicker way to achieve the same results?

Any help with this is really appreciated!

*DB fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8122334c63e76a8ab3e9041ee9dffc1f)*

**Update 1:**

This issue seems to only happen when the column os of type `text`.

Comment: You could use Window function if MySQL version > 8.0.2; or use Session variables

Comment: Thanks for the query and fiddle, but it would help us to see a more minimal problem.  Your query is fairly dense.

Comment: Your query looks wrong atleast the outer SQL is not confirm ANSI SQL standards on how to use GROUP BY.. MySQL extended GROUP BY feature can cause unrelated data.. Unless MySQL could have fetched the correct data with functional dependency for the columns which are not in the GROUP BY

Answer (score 1):

Since your [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=d67867c2124c40b5632b872aa8a07a8a) is for MariaDB version 10.3; I am presuming that you have [Window Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions-usage.html) available.

We can use [`Row_number()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_row-number) function over a partition of `group_id` to get row number values, as per the defined rules. Video with latest `last_update` value will have Row number of 1 and so on. If there is no video played, then the one with least value of Rank will have Row number = 1.

We can use this result-set as a Derived Table, and consider only those rows where Row number = 1.

```
SELECT 
  dt.user_id, 
  dt.group_id, 
  dt.video_id, 
  dt.video_title, 
  dt.time 
FROM 
(
  SELECT
     pt.user_id AS user_id,
     g.id       AS group_id,
     v.id       AS video_id,
     v.title    AS video_title,  
     pt.time    AS time,  
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY v.group_id 
                       ORDER BY pt.last_update DESC, 
                                v.`rank` ASC) AS row_num 
  FROM videos AS v
  INNER JOIN video_groups AS g 
    ON g.id = v.group_id AND 
       g.id IN (1,2) 
  LEFT JOIN user_video_play_times AS pt 
    ON pt.video_id = v.id AND 
       pt.user_id = 1 
) AS dt 
WHERE dt.row_num = 1
```

[**View on DB Fiddle**](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/h1mtHzYogL6MWsxaixCcFH/0)

**Result:**

```
| user_id | group_id | video_id | video_title       | time |
| ------- | -------- | -------- | ----------------- | ---- |
| 1       | 1        | 2        | Group 1 - Video 2 | 12   |
|         | 2        | 3        | Group 2 - Video 1 |      |
```

---

PS: **Note** that `Rank` is a [Reserved Keyword](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html#keywords-8-0-detailed-R), and you should really avoid using it as column/table name.